# Quick SQL error

Tags: mysql, sql, clause

I am having some issues with a query and i cant seem to be able to figure it out. Any ideas?

Works

```
SELECT * FROM `InviteKeys` WHERE `Value` = `1234567890123456`
```

Doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM `InviteKeys` WHERE `Value`  =  `VPx46RG2an1IqaBD`
```

Comment: Use single quotes around values not backticks

Comment: Can you pst it as an answer so i can answer?

Comment: Check the answer i posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single Quotes. It will work

```
SELECT * FROM InviteKeys WHERE Value  =  'VPx46RG2an1IqaBD'
```